# Uniform printing across all printers (when printing, not as a PDF)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pdf, printing

Below is the code that was put together by my developer but we're still having problems printing uniformly from http://sandboxalleninvestments.com/person/keith-albritton/. It prints fine when printing as a PDF but outside of that, it's all wonky. I'm out of time and running out of hair to pull out. On some printers it works on some days, on other it does not.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    // $post_id = get_the_id();
?>
<style>
@media print {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .bio__content {
        max-width: none;
    }
    .bio__content p { 
        font-size:16px !important; }
    }
    .subheader--bio .tabelize__content h1 {
        font-size: 35px !important;
   }
    .bio__content hr {
        margin:0;
    }
    .bio__content p {
        padding:0 30px;
    }
} /* @media print */
</style>
 <div class="subheader subheader--bio">
        <img src="<?php the_field("bio_picture"); ?>" alt="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="tableize tableize--middle">
                <div class="tableize__cell">
                    <div class="tabelize__content">
                        <?php
                        $first_name = get_field('first_name');
                        $last_name = get_field('last_name'); ?>
                        <h1><?php echo $first_name . " " .     $last_name ?></h1>
                        <small><?php the_field('job_title');     ?></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <main class="main main--inner main--border">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bio__content">
                <div class="bio__bar">
                    <ul class="socials list--nostyle">
                        <?php if (get_field('facebook')) :  ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_field('facebook');    ?>"><svg role="img" class="icon icon--fb"><use xlink:href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/icons.svg#icon-fb' ?>"></use></svg></a>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (get_field('instagram')) : ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_field('instagram'); ?>"><svg role="img" class="icon icon--in"><use xlink:href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/icons.svg#icon-in' ?>"></use>  </svg></a>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                      <?php  if(get_field('team')) : ?> 
                     <a href="<?php the_field('team'); ?>" class="link link--lg">View Team Page</a>
                     <?php  endif; ?> 
                </div>
                <?php the_field('description'); ?>
                <hr>
                <div class="bio__footer">
                    <a href="" class="link link--lg" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print Bio</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>  
<?php 
get_footer();
?>
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem. You can see that the margins are way off and the font doesn't match the code (size-wise):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/93qDn.jpg

Comment: (General note: please don't add links to external sites when asking questions in lieu of asking a self-contained question. If you fix this, future readers will examine the site in question, which may no longer be there, or will no longer exhibit the problem at hand).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/93qDn.jpg You can see that the margins are way off and the font doesn't match the code (size-wise)

Comment: OK. Have you tried different browsers and operating systems? What browser/OS are you having difficulties with at present? Finding this out will show you if it is a problem with your site or if it is a browser-dependent problem.

Comment: Also, browsers just don't print very well - the web was not designed for paper, and the output you are getting may be as good as you'll get it. Are you sure this website needs to be printed? If it really does, just keep pretty PDF copies on the server, and link to them from each profile page.